# Support for multipart/form-data in Azure developer portal

Tags: azure, api-gateway

On an Azure subscription I've created an API Gateway, in which I registered an API that expose a method that accept in input a multipart/form-data request.

As can be seen in the following image, the API gateway developer portal, shows the correct content-type but the body is a simple texbox.
[image]

Instead, the swagger autogenerated by the API, shows the input disposition correctly as can be seen in the following image.
[image]

There is any way to force the API Gateway developer portal to show the input params correctly?